# layout customisation in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks

I have set my homepage layout to 2 columns with right sidebar what i want to do is, I want to put a block just above the footer of my homepage in such a way that it will cover full width of the page. Currently, I can't achieve that because my homepage is 2 columns with right sidebar, so it obviously leaves space at right part. Is there any way I can define block in my homepage which will cover full width? or any link which is helpful to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Just follow [**my answer on this recent thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941693/display-category-image-above-2-columns-layout-page-magento-ver-1-9-0-1/25947228#25947228).

Basically you need to create a structural block that should come just below the content section, but just above the footer section. This way structural block will appear after the content section, which is in 2 column right bar section.

Please note, instead of `2-column-left.phtml` that I have used in that answer, you need to call the structural block inside `2-column-right.phtml`.

Hope that helps

### Edit

It seems that the provided link is not working now. So I am now responsible to add a full solution here. Thanks for my friend @DavidManners to notify me. :-)

Basically we need to add a structural block in between content section and footer section. For this create a `local.xml` file and add this layout update.

File : `app/design/frotend/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
             <block type="core/text_list" name="block.after.content" as="after_content" translate="label">
                <label>Sub Content Area</label>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

By putting this content, we just added a new structural block inside `root` block. Here root block is what `page layout block`.  It determines which layout a page holds. So the template file corresponding to `root` block vary depend upon the layout we need. Suppose if we need a `2 column right` layout, then what we need to do is set the correpsponding template to this block. It would be done like this.

```
   <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

Now I assume your page is `2 column right` layout, then in that case, you need to add this content by manually editing the file.

File : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/page/2columns-right.phtml`

```
   <div class="main-container col2-right-layout">
        <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <div class="col-main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- here comes our custom content -->
    <div><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_content') ?> </div>
```

Here we are calling our block `after_content` manually. The position at which the block is calling is very important here. It should be in between the (`content, right`) blocks and `footer` block. This way our block will get a `full-page-width` access.

However the manual addition I have shown above should do in a custom theme. Dont do this in `base/default` theme. Always use a package theme other than `base/default` for better extendability. Additionally, if you need to include this block in every page layout, then you need to repeat the second operation in every other page layout template files. ie phtml files that comes inside `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/page/` directory.

Comment: the link seems to 404 :(

Comment: @DavidManners : oops. I think the questioner deleted that question. So you want to see the solution?

Comment: Yeah think so. Would be great to have the full solution here.

Comment: I will do it now. Give me five min

Comment: @DavidManners : Answer updated. I have recollected my memory as possible I can. Have a look.